# full page scroll vertical and horizontal

Tags: jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to make page looking like on image below. When I make that with fullPage.js and from page 1 click in navigation page 4 it goes to that page and when I scroll up it goes to page 2 because that is first slide in section. Is there any other plugin that can help me to make vertical and horizontal scroll page by page, and also have active class in navigation change on scroll?

Thanks in advance

[click to see image how site should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS4LJ.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried the fullPage.js extension [*Scroll Horizontally*](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrollHorizontally.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I scroll everything is great, but when I click in navigation to go to page 4 from page 1, and then scroll up it goes to page 2. Because that is first slide in that section, but I need to go to page 3 and then to page 2

Comment: Then no. Nothing exist to do so. And I personally believe it would be terrible from the user experience point of view.